# NSUserDefaults toggle switch doesn't stick after multitasking

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, tvos

This is a tvOS application. I want the background of my application to change based on a toggle switch in Settings using NSUserDefaults. The toggle switch is called "White background", identifier is "whiteBackground", and default is 'NO'.

With my current code, it works when the user clicks home, navigates to 'Settings', and taps the toggle. However, if the user double clicks the home button (backgrounding the app), navigates to 'Settings' via task switcher, then navigates back to the app through task switcher, the setting is reverted.

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

func registerDefaultSettings() {
    var appDefaults = ["whiteBackground": false]
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(appDefaults)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    registerDefaultSettings()
    uiSettings()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.uiSettings), name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}

func uiSettings() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if defaults.boolForKey("whiteBackground") {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    } else {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }   
}
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, `setBool(true, ...)` and `setBool(false, ...)` should be the other way around.

Comment: Your method to register default values is nonsense. Register `let appDefaults =  ["whiteBackground" : false]` nothing else, no reading, and **never** `valueForKey:`

Comment: @MartinR I believe how I have it is correct, as I want the toggle to be activated to mean the background is white. Really, I don't think those are even necessary, I just included them for the sake of trying everything.

Comment: @vadian I've simplified it. I was afraid of registerDefaults overriding the user's chosen settings, which is why I had it that way (i.e., only register "whiteBackground" default value to `false` if the value isn't set).

Comment: As the name implies a *default value* is considered until the user overwrites it the first time. Henceforward it's ignored. Never read a value just before registering it. Once again, that's nonsense. Please read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html)

Comment: @vadian Yes, I understand now. Thank you for clarifying. Unfortunately, task switching still causes the setting to revert to the previous selection.

Comment: Are you synchronising the defaults after inserting them?

Comment: @jarora Unless I'm mistaken, I'm not inserting anywhere within my application, only reading. The insert should take place within the Settings app.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's simple a fix as this

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       uiSettings()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not that simple, but I appreciate the answer.

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's simply the nature of NSUserDefaults. The settings are likely not being written to storage between changing the toggle and task switching to my application.